# Dynamic Vertical RecyclerView inside Vertical RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to show dynamic vertical recyclerview inside vertical recyclerview. For ex. consider file manager in that one folder can contain multiple files and folder, when I tap on folder it shows it's inside file or folder.

[image]

In Above screenshot you can see, One group have multiple member as well as multiple group.

As shown here, group **yjf** have **test** group as well as member.

I want to implement same UI using Recyclerview. Does anyone have an idea how to implement this?

Comment: If we see your requirement we don't need recycler view inside recycler view, just we need different view types in the adapter, one is for Header and another is for the item. It will work fine.

Comment: But header can contain another header and it's item, do you have any example on github

Comment: Search tree recycler view or multi-level recycler view in Google you will get lot. Ex: https://github.com/shineM/TreeView, https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView, https://github.com/TellH/RecyclerTreeView,https://github.com/sadra/NLeveLExpandableListView

Comment: Thank you so much, actually I am not getting proper word for that, thanks alot Muthukrishnan

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done using the Expandable recycler view library. Check here - https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/ This might help.

Comment: You can further add one more childViewHolder to the child.

Comment: No, Can childview contain another childview and so on?, Like A Folder can contain B folder can contain C folder so folder into folder, is that possible?

Comment: yeah, childholder can be any view, which can be an expandable recycler item itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should use
NestedScrollView
--RecyclerView-> Inside Recycler view Holder -> Use another Recycler View